# Convert [preferenceactivity] to [preference-activity]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

SO currently has a number of questions tagged [preferenceactivity](/questions/tagged/preferenceactivity).  It'd be nice if that tag were replaced with [preference-activty](/questions/tagged/preference-activty) for better name format conformance and legibility and the current tag synonimized to the new one.

Comment: The name of the class is [`PreferenceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html), not `Preference-Activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention is that most multi-word tags get a hyphen, except when they are names of things that don't have a hyphen in ordinary usage such as class names, library names, etc.

[android-activity](/questions/tagged/android-activity) is a bit of a special case; we are strongly encouraging folks in the Android tag to use tags prefixed with Android, since [activity](/questions/tagged/activity), [intent](/questions/tagged/intent) and other similar tags are hopelessly ambiguous.